# laravel PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS requires format array(classname, array(ctor_args)); the classname must be a string specifying an existing class

Tags: php, laravel

i was working on a laravel project then i installed a new package using composer and i found this error

PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS requires format array(classname, array(ctor_args)); the classname must be a string specifying an existing class

i tried to :-

1. revert to previous commit on git
2. remove vendor folder and composer.lock and reinstall
   all with no results

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What exactly is the question? If that error/warning comes from installing that package you found I'd suggest removing that package via composer. It could also help others help you if you posted what package you installed

Comment: i removed the package but no results also 
package was spatie/laravel-sitemap

Comment: What do you mean by no results? you have to mention what you you expect to get

Comment: i mean the same error is happening

Comment: Are you sure that error didn't already happen before installing that package? Because it looks like it is in no way using PDO related methods.

Comment: @kerbholz i have the same question also but i'm telling what was the scenario

Comment: Maybe run `composer dumpautoload` and `php artisan config:clear` and see if that helps anything. If not I suggest you make a new copy of the project and see if that error already occurs there. Also, the error doesn't show what file and linenumber that error occurs?

Comment: After running composer Update I am getting following error on terminal 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv() in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php on line 534

Answer (score 27):

Had the same problem here. 
Downgrading to *composer require doctrine/dbal=2.6.3* did the trick so far.

Comment: Saved hours to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem. After downgrading `doctrine/dbal 2.7` to `2.6.*`, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem after reinstalling a new OS (ubuntu 16.04), solved by running `composer update` then `composer dump-autoload`.

seems to be a problem with caching in composer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it turn out to be a configuration on Nginx, which was still pointing to the php7.0-fpm after I've upgraded to php 7.2.

I've just fix that on `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Comment: This was exactly the issue I was having. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edit composer.json:
 "doctrine/dbal": "2.8.*" to "doctrine/dbal": "2.4.*" and run composer update will resolve problems.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because i had a similar problem.

I upgraded from PHP 7.0 to PHP 7.2 and the problem started.

I knew it had to do with the server not the laravel application.

After search with no luck. I simply restarted my httpd.service and viola! It worked.

I guess this because i didn't restart the http server after the upgrade from PHP 7.0 to 7.2.

So just reboot the server or restart the http service might get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by removing `php7.0-common` package when I've installed both php7.0 and php7.2.

Initially, command-line was using php7.2 (`php -v`) but when I checked [`phpinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) in the browser it was using php7.0. That might have caused the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try updating your PHP version to 7 or 7.1